# Find matrix of f with respect to bases

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Question:

**Let f be a linear transformation from $P_2$ to $\mathbb{R^3}$ whose standard matrix is**

**A=$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$**

**a) evaluate $f(1+2x+x^2)$**

My answer: = $3x+4x^2$

**b) Find the matrix of $f$ with respect to the bases $B_1={(1+x,1-x+x^2,1)}$ of $P_2$ and $B_2=((1,1,1),(0,1,1),(1,0,1))$ of $\mathbb{R^3}$.**

I have no idea where to start with part b. Any help greatly appreciated. I have looked at online lectures and my text book but it's not making sense. If you can explain as simply as possible, that would be great.

Comment: Are you familiar with change of basis? Because that is what they are essentially asking you to do.

Comment: I am but I don't know how to apply it in this particular situation.

Comment: Are you able to determine what the basis was that was used to create the matrix representation $A$ of your function $f$?

Comment: As I said in my question, I don't know how to attempt this question.

Comment: You want to express the basis vectors used to create $A$ as a linear combination of the vectors which form the basis for which you would like to find the matrix of $f$ with respect to. Does that make sense?

Comment: https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/changebasis/ this link might also help.

Comment: No it doesn't sorry.

Comment: I have Googled this question and done many hours of research trying to understand. If I could understand the processes on websites I would be able to do this question. I can't, this is why I have posted in Stack Exchange. If you cannot help, please stop commenting and allow someone else to assist. If you can help, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Is this correct then:

$f(1+x)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$
$f(1-x+x^2)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$
$f(1)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Which gives me transition matrix:
$P_{B_1>P_2}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Then I have transition matrix: 
$P_{B_2>\mathbb{R^3}}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Solving for

$[f]_{B_2,B_1}=(P_{B_2>\mathbb{R^3}})^-1 A P_{B_1>P_2}$
$=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$[f]_{B_2,B_1}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & -1 \\ 4 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your answer to a) should be the vector $(0,3,4)$ rather than the polynomial that you gave, since $f$ is a map to $\Bbb R^3$

As for the second question, an example computation example: we calculate 
$$
f(1 + x) = (1,0,2) = (-1)(1,1,1) + (1)(0,1,1) + (2)(1,0,1)
$$
So, the first *column* of your transformation matrix will be $(-1,1,2)$.